# Is exponentialRampToValueAtTime from Web Audio Api synchronous?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have this doubt and I can not find any info about it.

I am using [exponentialRampToValueAtTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/exponentialRampToValueAtTime) to turn down/up the volume of an oscillator. I have to do some process after this is already done but I am not sure if this method runs synchronously or do I need to wait manually ( `setTimeout()`) for it to end and than run my code.

It does not have some kind of `.then()` callback so I am not really sure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  None of the scheduling calls are synchronous.  You'll have to use setTimeout or the like to approximate the end timing.